# flask-oidc - Token required but invalid - with google sso

Tags: python, flask, openid-connect

**edit**
***I just realized how stupid my question is. Google doesn't authorise that way. I need to implement my own authorisation service and ask from him. Keycloak already implements that way***

I'm trying to access a ressource which is protected by an authorisation layer. I'm actually using the example code of flask-oidc.
I can authenticate nicely from my google account, but I can't access to my api endpoint because the token is said to be invalid.

I think the problem come from the client_secrets json but I'm not sure since the flask-oicd is kind of opaque when debugging.

**client_secrets.json**

```
    {
  "web": {
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "userinfo_uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://127.0.0.1:5000/oidc_callback"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here my code, which is kind the same of the example with few modifications:

**app.py**

```
import json
import logging

from flask import Flask, g
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update({
    'SECRET_KEY': 'SomethingNotEntirelySecret',
    'TESTING': True,
    'DEBUG': True,
    'OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS': 'client_secrets.json',
    'OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD': 'client_secret_post',
    'OIDC_TOKEN_TYPE_HINT': 'access_token',
    'OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE': False,
    'OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
})


oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    if oidc.user_loggedin:
        return ('Hello, %s, <a href="/private">See private</a> '
                '<a href="/logout">Log out</a>') % \
            oidc.user_getfield('email')
    else:
        return 'Welcome anonymous, <a href="/private">Log in</a>'


@app.route('/private')
@oidc.require_login
def hello_me():
    info = oidc.user_getinfo(['email', 'openid_id'])
    return ('Hello, %s (%s)! <a href="/">Return</a>' %
            (info.get('email'), info.get('openid_id')))

@app.route('/api')
@oidc.accept_token(True, ['openid'])
def hello_api():
    return json.dumps({'hello': 'Welcome %s' % g.oidc_token_info['sub']})


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    oidc.logout()
    return 'Hi, you have been logged out! <a href="/">Return</a>'
```

So I can loggin, but can't access at:

```
@app.route('/api')
@oidc.accept_token(True, ['openid'])
def hello_api():
```

where I get an:

```
{"error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Token required but invalid"}
```

The doc says:

```
 accept_token(require_token=False, scopes_required=None, render_errors=True)

    Use this to decorate view functions that should accept OAuth2 tokens, this will most likely apply to API functions.

    Tokens are accepted as part of the query URL (access_token value) or a POST form value (access_token).

    Note that this only works if a token introspection url is configured, as that URL will be queried for the validity and scopes of a token.
```

My two problems are:

- this token introspection url is documented nowhere on the doc. Is this the same as the token_uri?
- I can't debug and only see a 401 from flask. That's doesn't help me to understand what it has done. Is there a way to see what oicd called in background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google does not have a direct token introspection endpoint. They provide a tokeninfo endpoint for id token validation - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint

Comment: Also, I will suggest you to use your own implementation on API protection with access token. As you see, Google suggest you to use ID token for API authentication. But this may be not the case with all other identity providers. Please go through full article I given above

Comment: Thanks. Actually that make sense: Google can't introspect my own API service and I should implement my own API protection like you suggested. I think I misunderstood authentification with google, and authorising my own API with my own token. I know keycloak can do this. Thanks for confirming my doubt as I can be really dumb.

Comment: May be you should compose an answer for this. That way others will know the answer for this. Also, no one is dumb ;) it's matter of realizing some unknown facts .!!

Comment: how did yo solve it? @MrBonjour